# Vb.net not closing file after reading from it

Tags: windows, vb.net, streamreader

When refreshing my application, I have to read from a text file which has information stored in it. After it is read I make sure I have closed it 'file.close()' the next time I refresh the applicaztion the text file should be generated again and overright the previous one.

The problem is that it cant change the file because it is aparantly in use by another process but as soon as I close my application it works fine. Is there anyway to stop the process before refreshing it so it works correctly? The text file is called NetworkInfo.txt.

Thanks
Chris

EDIT

Every time I refresh the application I run a batch file that generates a file with all the network info in. (IPConfig/all)

I then have a module that reads from it like the following:

```
Public Function EthDefaultGateway() As String
    Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(ipconfig)
    Try

        Dim foundEthernet As Boolean = False
        Dim gateway As String = ""

        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()

            If line.Contains("Ethernet adapter LAN:") OrElse line.Contains("Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:") Then
                foundEthernet = True
            End If

            If foundEthernet Then
                If line.Contains("Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :") Then
                    gateway = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        If gateway = "" Then
            gateway = "Unknown"
        End If
        If gateway = "::" Then
            gateway = "Unknown"
        End If
        Return gateway
    Catch ex As Exception
        EthDefaultGateway = "Unknown"
    End Try
    sr.Close()
    sr.Dispose()
End Function
```

From this I gather all the bits of information I need. (There probs is a lot better way of doing this but Im only a nooby and I cant find any other ideas on here, the web or from friends.)

All of these close the file after readinf from it (sr.close)

Some reason though its not closing it. The only other thing It could be is the batch file isnt closing it which I think is very unlikely

The problem is that when I change the IP or refresh the form it fails because the batch file cannot over write the network info file.

Any suggestions?

I was just thinking of a way to kill the process after the refresh but I didnt know if this was a good idea or if it was doable or how to do it tbh.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's hard to provide an answer when we can't see what it is you're doing.  It sounds like you're not disposing the stream properly, but without any code it's hard to say.

Comment: Post updated. Sorry for not posting code:P

Comment: `the text file should be generated again and overright the previous one`  I think we might need to see this code, too.

Comment: `sr.close()` only closes the file; it doesn't release the `StreamReader`, so it's being retained until GC (garbage collection) cleans it up. Set `sr` to nothing after the close - not a vb.net guy, so I won't post an answer showing how. In C#, you'd put the code in a `using` block to auto-dispose of the stream, but I'm not sure how you'd do the same in vb.net.

Comment: @KenWhite I thought the StreamReader calls Dispose in the Close method.  Looks like it in the source code.

Comment: @LarsTech: I don't think so, but as I said in my previous comment I'm not a vb.net guy. In C#/Delphi Prism, which I'm much more familiar with, you have support for a `using` block that will automatically call `Dispose()` when it ends to release the resource. I can't speak for vb.net (which is why I posted a comment and not an answer). :-)

Comment: It doesn't close if you have an exception, should be closed in  Finally as part of the try / catch, sr needs to be declared before the  try statement

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the sr.dispose() and had no luck with that. I will try Orns idea. Isnt ther a way you can close the process? The batch file just throws the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Comment: Still get the same result after declaring the reader before the try

Comment: For debugging purposes, comment out the Try...Catch.  If you don't put the sr object in a using bracket, then you have to call the sr.close method in the Finally bracket, which you don't have.

Comment: You need to move your `Return gateway` to **after** the `sr.Dispose()` - you're returning from the function before it gets to the part that closes and disposes of the StreamReader.

Comment: Thanks for this! I spend a day of trying to get documents to close properly and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

```
    Return gateway
```

That bypasses the sr.Close() call at the bottom.  So the file won't be closed.  Always favor using the Using statement so it is automatic and can't be forgotten or skipped or bypassed because of an exception:

```
Public Function EthDefaultGateway() As String
    Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(ipconfig)
       '' Rest of your code
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: +1. This handles both the Dispose() issue and the early return.

Comment: Thanks. After pratting around with the code and installer,I managed to kill the program haha. Good job I have backups:P Il give this ago once I get it up running again. Seems like it will fix the problem. 

(The strange thing is that Im using one of my old backups. Very little has changed and yet the problem doesnt happen. looks up info from same file in same way but still no errors. Either way. Will be a good idea to get this fixed. Thanks again