# How Could Disconnect From Local JSON File?

Tags: vb.net, stream, json.net

I need to download every 10 minute a JSON file in to my project. (Older file delete and new file replace it)
and between delete and replace last process read data from data with newtonsoft.json library, so far so good.

Now my problem: after read data from JSON file, delete old data cancel and say file used by other program and cant replace it new JSON file

```
Dim Sreader As StreamReader = File.OpenText("C:\Common\Current.json")
Dim Reader As JsonTextReader = New JsonTextReader(Sreader)
Dim Treader As JObject = CType(JToken.ReadFrom(Reader), JObject)


S1 = Treader.SelectToken("current.temp_c").ToString()
```

Comment: Use the [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) to open the `Stream` and `StreamReader`, it will be closed when the body of the `Using` statement terminates.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978994) by Hans Passant to [Vb.net not closing file after reading from it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11978345).

Comment: Beyond that, I'm having some difficulty understanding your problem.  Is your problem that you don't know how to delete a file?  That you don't know how to download a file?  That you don't know how to detect when a file has been replaced in the filesystem?  That you don't know how to schedule a task that executes every 10 minutes?  Or is some exception being thrown somewhere that you need help to resolve?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/, then please try to [edit] your question to explain your question more precisely, and explain what answer you need.  However, very broad questions like "How can I write an application that downloads a JSON file every 10 minutes, deserializes it into some in-memory data model, then informs the UI of changes in the JSON data" are likely to be closed as being [too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259857) so please try to break your problem down into discrete, answerable portions.  Good luck!

Comment: I suspect this asker is not a native English speaker. My guess is that this process is locking the other process which deletes and replaces the JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Using Sreader As StreamReader = File.OpenText("C:\Common\Current.json")
Using Reader As New JsonTextReader(Sreader)
    Dim Treader As JObject = CType(JToken.ReadFrom(Reader), JObject)
    S1 = Treader.SelectToken("current.temp_c").ToString()
    '...
End Using
End Using
File.Delete("C:\Common\Current.json")
```

Separate from this, as an extra precaution it's easy to **rename** the file to include the current date and time prior to opening it. This will at least protect against a locked file issue from blocking additional updates.

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\Common\Current.json"
Dim tempPath As String = $"C:\Common\Current-{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.json"

File.Move(filePath, tempPath)
Using Sreader As StreamReader = File.OpenText(tempPath)
Using Reader As New JsonTextReader(Sreader)
    Dim Treader As JObject = CType(JToken.ReadFrom(Reader), JObject)
    S1 = Treader.SelectToken("current.temp_c").ToString()
    '...
End Using
End Using
File.Delete(tempPath)
```